# How to calculate a map LatLngBound from center and zoom manually?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I'm trying to render Google map using [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps). 
I get the users current location using `geolocation.navigator` function before the map is fully loaded, but I need to calculate the bounds of the map using the location of the user as the center and a preset zoom level , say , 5.
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this is how i manage to calculate the bounds of a map manually given a center, which in turn is returned by `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` function.

This calculation based on the conversion of latitude degree to kms where 1 degree of latitude change equals approximately 111.2 km. I am calculating bounds of the map from a latLng with 10km width.

```
const geolocation = (
    navigator.geolocation ? 
        navigator.geolocation :
        ({
            getCurrentPosition(success, failure) {
            failure(`Your browser doesn't support geolocation.`);
        },
    })
);

geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
   (position) => {
      if (this.isUnmounted) { return; }
          this.setState({
             center: {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude,
             }
          });

         // formula to find the South west and North East points from lat,lon between 10km.
         let lat_change = 10/111;
         let lon_change = Math.abs(Math.cos(this.state.center.lat *(Math.PI/180)));
         let sw_lat = this.state.center.lat - lat_change;
         let sw_lon = this.state.center.lng - lon_change;
         let ne_lat = this.state.center.lat + lat_change;
         let ne_lon = this.state.center.lng + lon_change;

         console.log(sw_lat, sw_lon, ne_lat, ne_lon);
         console.log(this.state.center);
   },
   (reason) => {
       if (this.isUnmounted) { return; }
       this.setState({
           center: geoMap.INITIAL_CENTER,
           zoom: 5
       });
   }
);
```

You can also go for a loader or spinner till the map is completely loaded and getBounds as @Fabian mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to set the default zoom to `5` on the Google Maps component:

```jsx
<GoogleMap
  ref="map"
  defaultZoom={5}
  defaultCenter={{ lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922 }}
>
```

`defaultCenter` is the user's location in this format.

and then get the bounds like this:

```
let map = this.refs.map;
let bounds = map.getBounds();

let geoBounds = {
  swLat: bounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
  swLng: bounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
  neLat: bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
  neLng: bounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
};
```

Comment: this can only be implemented only after the map component is loaded and mounted else `undefined` error is caused. My use case is that  I want to display clustered data on map load which is fetched from my backend api in nodejs where the map bounds are the params.

Comment: V3 of the Google Maps API has no built in function for this. If I was you I would put a loading indicator somewhere and load in the data after the Map was initialized - instead of showing nothing for a while. The user then can already see their position on the Map and shortly after the data is being displayed. IMHO.

Comment: a spinner or a loader seems a good idea. thanks  a ton @Fabian. I am working on calculating bounds manually and will post what i come up with soon

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it with react google map:

```
centralizeOnMyLocation = () => {
  const { maps, map } = this.state;
  const { userLocation } = this.props;
  const center = {
    lat: userLocation.latitude,
    lng: userLocation.longitude,
  };
  const extendedZoomAccuracy = 0.005;
  const bounds = new maps.LatLngBounds();

  bounds.extend(center);

  if (bounds.getNorthEast().equals(bounds.getSouthWest())) {
    const extendPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(
      bounds.getNorthEast().lat() + extendedZoomAccuracy,
      bounds.getNorthEast().lng() + extendedZoomAccuracy
    );
    bounds.extend(extendPoint);
  }

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  map.setCenter(center);
};
```